# Rails omniauth "Could not authenticate you from Line because "Invalid credentials"."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth, ruby-on-rails-6

I had perfectly working omniauth authorization, but recently I have found, that now it is invalid. When I click on "Line" login button, it redirects me to Line side authorization page, and there I click on "Enter" button, and it redirects me back to my site, but instead of authorization, I see this message
`Could not authenticate you from Line because "Invalid credentials".`

I had same error with facebook, but I have added `token_params: { parse: :json }` and problem is gone. After all I finished without this parameter at all, but anyway - for :line provider it doesn't work. I've tried to add it in `initializers/omniauth.rb`:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :line,
    Application.credentials[:omniauth][:line_channel_id],
    Application.credentials[:omniauth][:line_secret_id],
    token_params: { parse: :json }
end
```

And I have tried to add it to `devise.rb` (same way as :faceboook provider):

```
config.omniauth :line, Application.credentials[:omniauth][:line_channel_id],
                         Application.credentials[:omniauth][:line_secret_id],
                         token_params: { parse: :json }
```

I have tried to change gem `omniauth-line` version from '0.0.5' to '0.0.3', but it doesn't make sense. The worst of all, I don't know when it has been broken. I suppose after I've added `gem 'omniauth-rails_csrf_protection', '~> 0.1'` to my Gemfile. But I've already tried to remove it, and nothing changed. Of course I've checked twice the credentials, and it is absolutely correct. But it doesn't work nor in production nor in development mode.

In logs I found this:

Started

```
GET "/users/auth/line/callback?code=dqutKmHp3..."

ERROR -- omniauth: (line) Authentication failure! invalid_credentials: OAuth2::Error, invalid_grant: redirect_uri does not match
{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"redirect_uri does not match"}
```

And same error in any environment, production, local, staging.

when I run `rake routes` I can see this action:

```
user_line_omniauth_callback GET|POST /users/auth/line/callback(.:format)
```

In Line test account setting page, I can see `Callback URL`:

```
http://localhost:3000/users/auth/line/callback
```

But why this error occurs, I still don't understand.

Thank you so much for any help, guys!

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same problem. After searching I found the gem version is suspicious

Upgrade `omniauth-line` to latest version. Now (27/04/2023) is `0.1.0`

It works for me!!!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue, but instead of using the desired omniauth gem, I opted to implement a solution from scratch to stay in sync with the Current Line OAuth version(V2.1). I'll provide the code for this alternative approach.

https://github.com/smapira/line-rails-app-sandbox/blob/main/app/controllers/line_login_api_controller.rb